# MYSQL : If no data

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query:

```
$products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dpweb_products WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($products);
```

What I would like to know is if this row is empty:

```
$row['description']
```

I want it to display "No Product Description Available" but otherwise display the description value from the database.

Could do with pointing in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: How are you currently checking the value of `$row['description']`? What errors/unexpected results are you getting by using that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (empty($row['description'])
    echo 'No Product Description Available';
else
    echo $row['description'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $row['description'] === '' ? 'No Product Description Available' : $row['description'];
```

Comment: The op did not describe what "empty" means. Maybe it is a NULL field with a NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dpweb_products WHERE id='$id'");

if($products === false){ // better way to handle querys

    echo 'There was a problem with the query';

} else {

    if(mysql_num_rows($products) == 0) {

        echo 'No Product Description Available';

    }else{

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($products);
    echo $row['description'];

    }
}
```

`die();` will kill the page. You might not want this.